# Is Class.forName prohibited inside the J2EE container in general and weblogic in particular?

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, performance

I have performance problem while doing first API call to my J2EE applications. So I wanted to do Class.forName to preload the classes while doing application initialization. But I heard that it is prohibited by J2EE standard/BEA implementation (I might be completely wrong). Is it so? Are there any other limitation of doing forName in J2EE container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have performance problem while doing first API call to my J2EE applications. So I wanted to do Class.forName to preload the classes while doing application initialization.

So basically, you just want to move the overhead :) I don't see the difference (user experience maybe) but ok, why not.

> But I heard that it is prohibited by J2EE standard/BEA implementation (I might be completely wrong). Is it so? Are there any other limitation of doing forName in J2EE container.

The context is a bit unclear but, to my knowledge, it isn't. And that's actually something that the Pet Store app is/was doing. Quoting [EJB Restrictions](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/qanda/ejb_tier/restrictions.html):

> #### Why all the restrictions on creating class loaders and redirection of input, output, and error streams?
>
> Class loading is allowed, but creating
>   custom loaders is not, for security
>   reasons. These restrictions exist
>   because the EJB container has
>   responsibility for class loading and
>   I/O control. Allowing the EJB to
>   perform these functions would
>   interfere with proper operation of the
>   Container, and are a security hazard.
>
> The Java Pet Store has code that loads
>   classes from inside an enterprise bean
>   class using `Class.forName()`, in
>   [StateMachine](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/code/jps11/src/com/sun/j2ee/blueprints/petstore/control/ejb/StateMachine.java.html).

But why don't you just try it?

#### Reference

- [Questions and Answers - Enterprise JavaBeans Tier - EJB Restrictions](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/qanda/ejb_tier/restrictions.html)

Comment: Regarding "So basically, you just want to move the overhead :) I don't see the difference (user experience maybe) but ok, why not.", my API takes around 1 min - 5 min, when first time I call it.. so timeout occurs for most of the time; when i bounce weblogic server

Comment: @j2eehacker Ok, I see. But where are you going to make that call if you move it?